# Trying to measure how much time an insert takes in a database

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap, sortedset, nanotime

I have a `Multithreaded program` which will insert into one of my table and that program I am running like this-

> java -jar CannedTest.jar 100 10000

which means:

- Number of threads is `100`
- Number of tasks is `10000`

So each thread will insert `10000 records` in my table. So that means `total count (100 * 10000)` in the table should be `1,000,000` after program is finished executing.

I am trying to measure how much time an insert is taking into my table as a part of our LnP testing. I am storing all these numbers in a `ConcurrentHashMap` like how much time an insert into database is taking like below.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();

callableStatement[pos].executeUpdate(); // flush the records.

long end = System.nanoTime() - start;

final AtomicLong before = insertHistogram.putIfAbsent(end / 1000000L, new AtomicLong(1L));
if (before != null) {
    before.incrementAndGet();
}
```

When all the threads are finished executing all the tasks, then I try to print out the numbers from the `ConcurrentHashMap insertHistogram`     by sorting it on `Key` which is `Milliseconds` and I get the result like below-

```
Milliseconds           Number
0                      2335
1                      62488
2                      60286
3                      54967
4                      52374
5                      93034
6                      123083
7                      179355
8                      118686
9                      87126
10                     42305
..                      ..
..                      ..
..                      ..
```

And also, from the same `ConcurrentHashMap insertHistogram` I tried to make a Histogram like below.

```
17:46:06,112  INFO LoadTest:195 - Insert Histogram List:
17:46:06,112  INFO LoadTest:212 - 64823 came back between 1 and 2 ms
17:46:06,112  INFO LoadTest:212 - 115253 came back between 3 and 4 ms
17:46:06,112  INFO LoadTest:212 - 447846 came back between 5 and 8 ms
17:46:06,112  INFO LoadTest:212 - 330533 came back between 9 and 16 ms
17:46:06,112  INFO LoadTest:212 - 29188 came back between 17 and 32 ms
17:46:06,112  INFO LoadTest:212 - 6548 came back between 33 and 64 ms
17:46:06,112  INFO LoadTest:212 - 3821 came back between 65 and 128 ms
17:46:06,113  INFO LoadTest:212 - 1988 came back greater than 128 ms
```

NOTE:- The database in which I am trying to insert records, it's in `Memory Only` mode currently.

**Problem Statement:-**

Take a look at this number in my above result which prints out by sorting it on the key-

`0                      2335`

I am not sure how it is possible that `2335 calls` was inserted in `0 milliseconds`? And also I am using `System.nanotime` while measuring the insert.

Below is the code which will print out the above logs-

```
private static void logHistogramInfo() {

    int[] definition = { 0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 };
    long[] buckets = new long[definition.length];

    System.out.println("Milliseconds           Number");
    SortedSet<Long> keys = new TreeSet<Long>(Task.insertHistogram.keySet());
    for (long key : keys) { 
       AtomicLong value = Task.insertHistogram.get(key);
       System.out.println(key+ "                      " + value);
    }

    LOG.info("Insert Histogram List: ");
    for (Long time : Task.insertHistogram.keySet()) {
        for (int i = definition.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (time >= definition[i]) {
                buckets[i] += Task.insertHistogram.get(time).get();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < definition.length; i++) {
        String period = "";
        if (i == definition.length - 1) {
            period = "greater than " + definition[i] + " ms";
        } else {
            period = "between " + (definition[i] + 1) + " and " + definition[i + 1] + " ms";
        }
        LOG.info(buckets[i] + " came back " + period);
    }

}
```

I am not sure why `0` milliseconds is getting shown when I try to print the values from the Map directly by sorting it on the key.

But the same `0 milliseconds` doesn't get shown when I try to make the histogram in the same `logHistogramInfo method`.

Is there anything wrong I am doing in my calculation process in my above method?

Comment: *"So each thread will insert 10000 records in my table."* I suspect that 1 update of 100,000 records will be faster then 10 updates of 10,000 records.  I'd try it both ways before jumping to conclusions about which is faster.

Comment: In my question above, I am not trying to see which one is faster, I am trying to figure it out why I am getting `0 milliseconds` while using System.nanotime. Correct me if I misinterpreted your suggestion.